# What's the meaning of "java class ｜" computation

Tags: java, bit, operation

```
public void run() {
     final V value;
     try {
       value = getDone(future);
     } catch (ExecutionException e) {
       callback.onFailure(e.getCause());
       return;
     } catch (RuntimeException | Error e) {
       callback.onFailure(e);
       return;
     }
     callback.onSuccess(value);
   }
```

I think the "|" computation is a kind of bit computation, and it can be applied to byte, int, long and so on. But what's the meaning when "|" symbol applied to some java classes?

```
RuntimeException | Error e
```

Comment: This is called multi-catch block introduced in Java 7. Kindly read some tutorials!

Answer (score 0):

It is to catch multiple exceptions inside a single catch block

```
try{
}
catch(Exception1 | Exception2 | Exception2 e){
   callSomething()
}
```

equivalent to :

```
try{
}
catch(Exception1 e){
   callSomething()
}
catch(Exception2 e){
   callSomething()
}
catch(Exception3){
   callSomething()
}
```

Comment: Does it work the same way as the logical OR (||) would work in an If statement or is it a different mechanism?

Comment: it is same as the logical OR

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I ask another question ?
Either Exception1 or Exception2 is a java class, why can "|" symbol be applied to a java class?

Comment: @lainan it is a simple OR statement. So what the expression means Try{....} catch(Exception1 OR Exception2). The Exceptions are defined by there respective classes

Comment: these exception classes are not overlapping each other. that is why the operator is used. In the normal operator OR(||) both can be TRUE. In here class is either E1 or E2. For classes overlap represents the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
catch (RuntimeException | Error e) {
```

means you are actually defining a block for catching either a RuntimeException **OR** an Error

that was introduced since java7

here more info about it:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

---

the explained pretty well

Consider the following example, which contains duplicate code in each of the catch blocks:

```
catch (IOException ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
catch (SQLException ex) {
     logger.log(ex);
     throw ex;
}
```

In releases prior to Java SE 7, it is difficult to create a common method to eliminate the duplicated code because the variable ex has different types.

The following example, which is valid in Java SE 7 and later, eliminates the duplicated code:

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```